# Countertop repair

Tags: bathroom

Someone left a waterbottle on our bathroom countertop and it looks like it stripped off the paint. Can this be fixed? Thanks. [image]

Comment: looks more like something was deposited there. Have you tried a bit of elbowgrease to get it off?

Comment: It really seems like the paint is coming off.

Comment: Water, not alcohol? Looks very similar to alcohol damage on susceptible finishes. A paint/finish easily damaged by water would be an odd choice in a bathroom.

Comment: nail varnish remover could be a candidate for causing the damage. But it will need re coating completely...

Comment: Yeah I found out it was face cleaner which had alcohol.

Comment: alcohol will attack acrylic paints.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, once paint becomes damaged, your choices are limited to touching up the existing paint, or refinishing the entire surface.

Touch-up is usually not seamless because its almost impossible to find the exact paint and color that was used previously.  On a countertop, it's probably some industrial type of finish that's not available to the public anyway.  You can get *close* with house paint or hobby paint, but it's going to leave a mark.

To ensure a solid, seamless finish, you will most likely have to re-coat the entire top with an appropriate material.

Comment: Not quite sure how "industrial" it could possibly be since an average bathroom product damaged it.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I just meant a product that is not sold to the public or requires special machinery to apply - something that would only be used in industry at a large scale.

Comment: In the photo it looks like brushed on acrylic latex to me.   paint tinting experts can match colours by eye remarkably well. and those color matching computers allow the non-experts to a similar job.